# When we need to use product and current_product from Registry?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, registry

In Magento2, if we want the current category detail then we can retrieve it from Registry as below:

> $currentCategory = $this->_registry->registry('current_category');

For Getting current product detail, then we can retrieve it from Registry as below:

> $currentProduct = $this->_registry->registry('product');

OR

> $currentProduct = $this->_registry->registry('current_product');

So which one we should use or which one that Magento recommends for getting Current Product? why?

Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look:

*\Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product::initProduct()*

```
    // Register current data and dispatch final events
    $this->_coreRegistry->register('current_product', $product);
    $this->_coreRegistry->register('product', $product);
```

As we can see, Magento registers two variables. That why we can get by `current_product` and `product` variables. Seem that Magento wants to give us "more ways" to get the current product data in block, event,... via Registry.

See more:

*\Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Category\Widget\CategoriesJson::execute()*

```
    $this->_coreRegistry->register('category', $category);
    $this->_coreRegistry->register('current_category', $category);
```

Comment: Hello @Khoa,
Thanks alot for your quick response. I am agreed in the case of getting current Product. But for getting current category specially on Frontend, we should only use:
$currentCategory = $this->_registry->registry('current_category');

Comment: Yes, in category case I showed, it belongs to Admin area.